# Update Handler is not getting called

Tags: magento2, update-handle

I am following the exact same logic as CatalogRule. Everything is working properly. All data are saving in my `vendor_rule` table but website ids are not saving in my `vendor_rule_website`.

I do have `ReadHandler` and `SaveHandler` in place but `SaveHandler` is not getting called. When I manually add data to `vendor_rule_website` then it actually reads the website table. I have also confirmed that `ReadHandler` class is being called.

My `di.xml` file has this:

```
  <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Vendor\NameSpace\Api\Data\RuleInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="entityTableName" xsi:type="string">vendor_rule</item>
                <item name="identifierField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

     <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\AttributePool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendorRule" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="Vendor\NameSpace\Api\Data\RuleInterface" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="read" xsi:type="string">Vendor\NameSpace\Model\ResourceModel\ReadHandler</item>
                        <item name="create" xsi:type="string">Vendor\NameSpace\Model\ResourceModel\SaveHandler</item>
                        <item name="update" xsi:type="string">Vendor\NameSpace\Model\ResourceModel\SaveHandler</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\HydratorPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="hydrators" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Vendor\NameSpace\Api\Data\RuleInterface" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\EntityManager\AbstractModelHydrator</item>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

My `SaveHandler.php`:

```
namespace Vendor\NameSpace\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\AttributeInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveHandler
 */
class SaveHandler implements AttributeInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Rule
     */
    protected $ruleResource;

    /**
     * @var MetadataPool
     */
    protected $metadataPool;

    /**
     * @param Rule $ruleResource
     * @param MetadataPool $metadataPool
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\NameSpace\Model\ResourceModel\Rule $ruleResource,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool
    ) {
        $this->ruleResource = $ruleResource;
        $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $entityType
     * @param array $entityData
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute($entityType, $entityData, $arguments = [])
    {
        $linkField = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata($entityType)->getLinkField();
        if (isset($entityData['website_ids'])) {
            $websiteIds = $entityData['website_ids'];
            if (!is_array($websiteIds)) {
                $websiteIds = explode(',', (string)$websiteIds);
            }
            $this->ruleResource->bindRuleToEntity($entityData[$linkField], $websiteIds, 'website');
        }

        if (isset($entityData['customer_group_ids'])) {
            $customerGroupIds = $entityData['customer_group_ids'];
            if (!is_array($customerGroupIds)) {
                $customerGroupIds = explode(',', (string)$customerGroupIds);
            }
            $this->ruleResource->bindRuleToEntity($entityData[$linkField], $customerGroupIds, 'customer_group');
        }
        return $entityData;
    }
```

**Why is not my `SaveHandler` class getting called?** Is there another way to save associated tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds stupid, but yes, I was there.

I was missing the use of `entityManager` object save function in my resource class.

```
public function save(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
{
    $this->getEntityManager()->save($object);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager
 * @deprecated 100.1.0
 */
private function getEntityManager()
{
    if (null === $this->entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager::class);
    }
    return $this->entityManager;
}
```

**I am still not sure why `getEntityManager()` is deprecated, and what should I use instead.**